# Spring ehcache no such method error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ehcache

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCach
eFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V


    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]:
     Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework
    .cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy
    .instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
            ... 192 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCach
    eFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
            at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.<init>(EhCacheFa
    ctoryBean.java:101)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
    orAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
    onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:1
    47)
            ... 194 more
```

Comment: Which spring version do you use?

Comment: @Jens Using version 3.1.3 which working fine, but when tried to use version 4.1.4 I am getting this issue.

Comment: Looks like you need a newer version of ehcahe. Update to the latest version 2.9 and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Error seems to be quite clear

[Version 2.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheFactoryBean.html) that you use does not have the method.

[Version 4.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheFactoryBean.html) of EhCacheFactoryBean seems to have the method.

I guess you have mixed incompatible versions of jars.

Comment: Where do we get version 4.1 or ehcache, I am seeing version 2.9 is final

Comment: sorry, I am not able to edit my comments, yes I am using spring version 4.1.4, for this dont know which version of ehcache to be used

Answer (score 1):

The method `setMaxEntriesLocalHeap` used in `EhCacheFactoryBean` is in the father class `CacheConfiguration`, you can see the source code:

`public class EhCacheFactoryBean extends CacheConfiguration implements FactoryBean<Ehcache>, BeanNameAware, InitializingBean {
}`

it's not found maybe caused by `CacheConfiguration` hadn't been auto wired to the bean factory, you can check this.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a version mismatch in the lib you are trying to use. Rip down the jar and using [jdgui](http://code.google.com/p/innlab/downloads/detail?name=jd-gui-0.3.3.windows.zip&) see if the class is available.

The issue here is the lib you are using in the module and the one you are referring are different hence the exception.

Comment: I am getting this issue when I am using Spring version 4.x and ehcache dependency 2.5.0, it is working fine when using Spring version 3.x and ehcache version 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Jar files required :- spring-security 2.0.3 and spring 2.5.5 and echache 1.2.4
 ehcache config

```
 <ehcache>
 <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
 <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
</ehcache>
```

Spring  config:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheMa nagerFactoryBean">
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache-failsafe.xml" />
</bean>
<bean id="userCacheBackend" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFa ctoryBean">
<property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
<property name="cacheName" value="userCache" />
</bean>
<bean id="userCache" class="org.springframework.security.providers.dao. cache.EhCacheBasedUserCache">
<property name="cache" ref="userCacheBackend" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mvn dependency:tree` and check your versions of `org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar`is newer than `3.2.13.RELEASE`.

If so that means you need to use the EhCache in version 2.5 and newer. If you cannot, for example because you are using the `hibernate-ehcache` which requires 2.4.x ehCache then the only way is to use the old spring-context-support:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version><!-- version required by ehcache-core 2.4.8-->
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

It should work with the newer spring. I've exclude the dependencies to prevent downloading the old versions of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue and its resolved by upgrading to ehcache version 2.7.1